# Bindable property is not working on StackLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to make a custom control called switch label. I put label and switch inside the stack layout. My purpose is to make a control like SwitchCell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileRKE.Controls.SwitchLabel"
             Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label x:Name="lbTitle" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Switch x:Name="swtValue"
            IsToggled="{Binding IsOn}"
            VerticalOptions="Start"/>
</StackLayout>
```

code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SwitchLabel : StackLayout
{
    public SwitchLabel()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Title),
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(SwitchLabel),
        defaultValue: string.Empty,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsOnProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(IsOn),
        returnType: typeof(bool),
        declaringType: typeof(SwitchLabel),
        defaultValue: false,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public bool IsOn
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsOnProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsOnProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Do I write it in correct way?
I found that the binding is not firing when I bind a model into it

Answer (score 0):

I myself have hard time understing how exactly bindable properties work. 
But when that happens to me I add onpropertyChanged handler to the BindableProperty.Create() as a parameter. And reflect the change to the control in the view.

Anyway, regarding your case I do not think that you need to add bindable properties as IsToggled is already a bindable one. Just bind to boolean property in the viewmodel and this should work .